# Rails: save Google chart on server side

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, prawn

I use JavaScript in my view page to generate a Google Chart. I want to save it into my app/asset/images/ folder so I can display the Google chart in my prawnto PDF when the user click the display PDF button.

In my Rails view page, how can I save the chart to the images folder?

Here is my view page code:

```
  <!--Div that will hold the line chart-->
  <div id="line_chart" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>

  <!-- Display PDF -->
  <%= link_to "Display PDF", {:action => "index", :format => 'pdf'}, :target => '_blank' %>

  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <!--Load the Google JSAPI library-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
            'modules':[{ 'name':'visualization', 'version':'1', 'packages':['corechart'] }]}"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">//<!--Load the Google Visualization and chart libraries-->

    function showGraph() {
      // Load the Visualization API library and the piechart library.
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
      //Immediately after calling google.load(), your code should call google.setOnLoadCallback(my_handler), a Google JSAPI function that calls your handler as soon as all the libraries are loaded.
      //Your handler function should create and define the chart.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // My handler function is called drawChart
      // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        //First, create a DataTable
        var dt = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Number of people'],
          ['2005',   1000 ],
          ['2006',   1170 ],
          ['2007',   660  ],
          ['2008',   1030 ]
        ]);
        //Set chart options, inlcuding title and dimension
        var opt = {
          fontName: 'Arial',
          fontSize: 20,
        };

        //Instantiates a chart and specify which container does this chart will go to
        var ch = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));  //Here we instantiate a chart as a PieChart that will go into the container whose id is named line_chart

        //Using the above chart instance, draw a chart according to the datatable and options we defined earlier
        ch.draw(dt, opt);
      }
    }
    window.onload = showGraph();
  </script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Javascript and samples that show Google Charts to PDF as well as many other things. Without going to images.

http://www.cloudformatter.com/GoogleCharts

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the css2pdf and how to use it.

Comment: In addition, if you have experience with this plugin in rails, can you provide an example of how to produce a PDF for a Google line chart  using my code above? It would be very helpful to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a method to put the chart in an image:

> if you want to provide access to a PNG image of a chart, you can use
>   the getImageURI() method.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing

A problem is that you first need to call this in javascript, so normally in the browser, and send the image-uri then to the server for the pdf generation.

Google has also an API to create "static" charts as images, that is much easier to use here, unfortunately they say it is deprecated: (today it is still working, and they break a lot of pages when they turn it off...)

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/

In Prawn, you can include a remote picture with the help of `open_uri` 
At least, I found this in the old manual:

> If instead of an explicit filename, an object with a read method is
>   passed as file, you can embed images from IO objects and things that
>   act like them (including Tempfiles and open-uri objects).

```
require "open-uri"

Prawn::Document.generate("remote_images.pdf") do 
  image open("http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/media/prawn_logo.png")
end
```

But If you are just doing line charts, you can draw them in Prawn by yourself. This is really not so complex, and you get real vector graphics.

Comment: I think the getImageURI method only works for core chart like pie and bar chart, not the line chart. I may produce bar and pie chart using the Google chart API in the future, so I want to keep their looking consistent. Is there anyway I can get the image URI for the line chart?